# Iterate Keys with Values for Beam pipeline

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

After applying  .apply(GroupByKey.create()) I am getting values like PCollection<KV<Integer,Iterable>. Can you suggest how to apply further transforms for each key.

Ex: PCollection<KV<1,Iterable>
PCollection<KV<2,Iterable>
The keys are dynamic values. I need to iterate for each Key Present in the PCollection.

Comment: Can you share a code snippet please ?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use a DoFn / ParDo to iterate over such iterable.

I drafted a quick example to show how this can be done.

```java
    // Create sample rows
    PCollection<TableRow> rows =
        pipeline
            .apply(
                Create.of(
                    new TableRow().set("group", 1).set("name", "Dataflow"),
                    new TableRow().set("group", 1).set("name", "Pub/Sub"),
                    new TableRow().set("group", 2).set("name", "BigQuery"),
                    new TableRow().set("group", 2).set("name", "Vertex")))
            .setCoder(TableRowJsonCoder.of());

    // Convert into a KV of <group, name>
    PCollection<KV<Integer, String>> keyValues =
        rows.apply(
            "Key",
            MapElements.into(
                    TypeDescriptors.kvs(TypeDescriptors.integers(), TypeDescriptors.strings()))
                .via(row -> KV.of((Integer) row.get("group"), (String) row.get("name"))));

    // Group by key
    PCollection<KV<Integer, Iterable<String>>> groups =
        keyValues.apply("Group", GroupByKey.create());

    // Iterate and print group + values
    groups.apply(
        ParDo.of(
            new DoFn<KV<Integer, Iterable<String>>, Void>() {
              @ProcessElement
              public void processElement(@Element KV<Integer, Iterable<String>> kv) {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                for (String name : kv.getValue()) {
                  if (sb.length() > 0) {
                    sb.append(", ");
                  }
                  sb.append(name);
                }
                System.out.println("Group " + kv.getKey() + " values: " + sb);
              }
            }));

    pipeline.run();
```

Prints (note that the output is not ordered/guaranteed due to concurrency).

```
Group 2 values: BigQuery, Vertex
Group 1 values: Dataflow, Pub/Sub
```

Comment: I want to write the avroio write file for each key. Please suggest if any

Comment: You will likely have to do that on AvroIO. Can you please open another question with more details on what you want to do? This question asked how to iterate on grouped values.